# why is this equality between double and triple integral true?

Tags: calculus

Consider the solid

$$E=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2\le 4,\; z\ge-\sqrt{2}\}. $$

Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a vector field of class $C^1$ and $\sigma$ the spherical surface centered on the origin of radius $2$, above the plane $z = -\sqrt{2}$ and oriented according to the outside normal. So

$$\iint_{\sigma}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS=\iiint_E\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\,dV-\iint_{\sigma_1}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}_1\,dS. $$

My doubt is: why is this equality true?

I only thought that this equality was true (Gauss's theorem)

$$\iint_{\sigma}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS=\iiint_E\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\,dV. $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *closed* surface for Gauss' theorem.  And your $\sigma$ isn't.  No doubt, $\sigma_1$ is a surface that patches the hole in $\sigma.$  So the surface integral over the whole closed surface is

$$\iint_{\sigma} + \iint_{\sigma_1} $$

which by Gauss' theorem equals

$$\iiint_E.$$

So subtract the second double integral from both sides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why σ is not close? I guess a spherical surface is something close..

Comment: $\sigma$ is a sphere that has had a cap cut off.  There is a boundary at the place where the cut was made.  Closed surfaces don't have boundaries.   And if they're orientable, then there's an "inside" and an "outside", and no way for a bug to get from the inside to the outside.